# Packages to verify the re-rendering in es5 components other than "WhyDidYouRender"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, package

Right now I'm using the WhyDidYourender package to verify the component re-rendering but there are few components in my repo that uses es2015. WhyDidYouRender is not working in es2015 components. Seeing below error:

```
TypeError: Class constructor MyComponent cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

So need a way to verify the re-rendering for es5 components. Also, tried Chrome highlights to verify the re-rendering, please don't recommend that.
Any help is appreciated, Thanks!
WhyDidYouRender repo link: https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support the ES6 or not is rely on your Browser. It's more like you trying to use the class but there is no instance to access.

Transpiled to es5 class is available in [PR#8656](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/8656), the whole react class elements are supported to extend with this library. If you transpile your classes by ES5 or ES6, use below code:

```js
// traspiled to es5
const whyDidYouRender = require('@welldone-software/why-did-you-render);
// traspiled to es6
const whyDidYouRender = require('@welldone-software/why-did-you-render/dist/no-classes-transpile/umd/whyDidYouRender.min.js');
```

Comment: Thanks! That helps!